# Altium PCB Layout Track Issue

Tags: pcb-design, altium, layout, routing, tracking

My question is about the weird track figure in the Altium Layout. I attached a screenshot of this issue in the following. Can you help me, how to fix or remove this mark from Altium PCB page?

[image]

Comment: By the way, this weird track remains from the previous track I've drawn before. I completely deleted the track to redraw it again, but these signs didn't delete even if I deleted the routing.

Comment: Press shift-S first to show all layers, do another shift-S until you get into the all layer mode. You may then also choose to enable all used layers to see if you may have these remaining tracks on another layer that you can switch to and then delete them. Can you actually select these artifacts manually ?

Comment: I tried it repeatedly. I don't select it in any condition. Unfortunately, that is not a real track, it is like an artifact mark.

Comment: If you generate the Gerbers is there a file generated with these phantom tracks ? Switch all Gerbers on an generate them to verify file by file to see which layer (mechanical, copper etc.) it might be on ... Also have you contacted Altium to see if this is a known issue ?

Comment: BTW can you do a select ALL on ALL layers and then copy and paste to a completely new PCB document. Maybe the stuff will just go away if you only copy what can be selected ...